# Return coffeescript through AJAX call into Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I want to use Ruby to help me create coffeescript objects..

So I would like to be able to create a file like: (example.js.coffee.erb):

```
class Test
  @constructor: (@name) ->


window.new_obj = new Test(<%= some_ruby_code%>)
```

and on an AJAX request do:

```
$(document).ready ->

    $.ajax "/controller/action",
            type: "GET"
            error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
                  alert "Your search result came up empty. Please try again, or refresh the page."
            success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->    
                  #APPEND SCRIPT DIRECTLY INTO DOCUMENT THEN
                  console.log window.new_obj.name
                  #DO OTHER THINGS WITH DATA FROM example.js.coffee.erb
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How would I get the javascript to append to the document? I tried $(document).append(data)... and the example.js.coffee.erb having a simple alert statement in it, did not fire..

Comment: As an aside, that isn't how you write CoffeeScript constructors. You have an extra `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your AJAX request to retrieve and execute code, use `dataType: 'script'`.

Appending script to the DOM isn't going to do anything.

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **dataType**:
>   ...
>   "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.
>   ...

Comment: Getting closer.. The coffeescript doesnt compile though. It will work if I just use JS.

Comment: @Davey There is a gem called [coffeebeans](https://github.com/markbates/coffeeBeans) which, if I am reading it correctly, should be able to render the coffeescript to JS when a request is made for a "JS" format. I don't believe you need to do any extra work, other than what Meagar wrote. I cannot speak from personal experience, I merely stumbled upon it from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6227492/877472). Some of the other answers for that question might be of some help too.